# Weird issue with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

I'm using the html2canvas plugin to capture a screenshot of a page. It works fine when I use the following code:

```
var target = $('body');
html2canvas(target, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
});
```

in document.ready but when used outside document.ready like say on a button click I keep getting proxy issues related to the plugin like Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.